# Not able to retrieve Settings through Metadata API

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api, workbench, package.xml

I am trying to retrieve Settings Metadata using Metadata API.
The request body is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<soapenv:Header>
    <tns:SessionHeader>
        <tns:sessionId>{token}</tns:sessionId>
    </tns:SessionHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <tns:retrieve>
        <retrieveRequest>
            <unpackaged>
                <types>
                    <members>TrialOrg</members>
                    <name>Settings</name>
                </types>
                <types>
                    <members>RecordPage</members>
                    <name>Settings</name>
                </types>
                <version>54.0</version>
            </unpackaged>
        </retrieveRequest>
    </tns:retrieve>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The output is showing me error
[image]

But when I am trying to retrieve these same settings through workbench, I am able to successfully do it.
Here is my **package.xml**

[image: Package.xml]

Here is output from the workbench

[image]

Any lead, what I am doing wrong in the SOAP call.
anything would be highly appreciable

Comment: Security related note: Try to mask the secrets like session id when posting an example  otherwise it might be taken advantage of by some bad actors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `apiVersion` field in the [soap request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve_request.htm). I believe that field auto-populated by workbench. If you don't specify, sfdc will assume it as first supported version (in my case it was  12). You can check this by viewing the package.xml returned in the retrieve response.

Comment: Whatever listmetadata is showing in the response..
I am trying to retrieve those settings only..

Comment: +1
 <result>
                <createdById>0055f000002stKHAAY</createdById>
                <createdByName>Peter Parker</createdByName>
                <createdDate>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</createdDate>
                <fileName>settings/DevHub.settings</fileName>
                <fullName>DevHub</fullName>
                <lastModifiedById>0055f000002stKHAAY</lastModifiedById>
                <lastModifiedDate>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</lastModifiedDate> 
                <type>Settings</type>
            </result>
@metasync

Comment: Thanks, Buddy..!
This is working